# Is it safe to pass LARGE_INTEGER.QuadPart as out argument for size_t?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Func prototype:

```
foo(_out_ PSIZE_T arg);
```

Usage:

```
LARGE_INTEGER offset = {0};

foo(&offset.QuadPart); // Is it safe ?
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383713(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That documentation defines QuadPart as LONGLONG. <strike>[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) defines LONGLONG as a `__int64` in 64bit and `double` in 32 bit</strike>. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230344.aspx) defines `LONGLONG` as `__int64`.

If you compile for 32 bit, then it's definitely wrong, as size_t is an unsigned 32bit integer there. If you compile for 64 bit, it's *still* wrong, because size_t is an *unsigned* int and LONGLONG is signed.

So it's not correct in 64 bit either, because LONGLONG is signed and size_t is unsigned, as Steve noted.

Your compiler should flag it as an error anyway.

Comment: Also `size_t` is unsigned, whereas `LONGLONG` is signed.

Comment: That documentation is wrong. LONGLONG is not `double` in 64-bit or 32-bit on x86.  It is always `__int64`.

Comment: agree.. that is error in doc. hate all this datatypes mess. so LARGE_INTEGER is signed in64 and size_t is unsigned int64

Comment: signed vs unsigned is no problem at all, it's explicitly allowed to access an object via an lvalue of mismatched signedness.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7005988/103167